# Show OK dialog after data save, before redirect to same page (or refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page that allows the user to edit data on a database record. After the record is saved, the redirect takes you back to the same page. What I want is a popup with "Record saved." in it and an "OK" button. I realize this is pretty basic, but the popup happens before the save if I use just javascript (whether up front or from code-behind), which means you get a save message before any possible errors, and there's no popup at all if I use most of the code-behind solutions I've found. For example, in my page:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="JobPanel" HeaderText="Job Info">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="left_column" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="SaveAll" 
                        OnClientClick="setConfirmUnload(false);" 
                        runat="server" Text="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

In my code-behind, I have tried:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "popup", 
    "alert('Record saved successfully.');
    window.location='EditJob.aspx?
    JOBID='" & txtJobID.Text, True)
```

then

```
Dim msg As String = "Job saved."
Dim script As String = "alert('" & msg & "');"
script += "window.location.href = 'EditJob.aspx?JOBID='" & txtJobID.Text
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), "saved", script, True)
```

then

```
Response.Redirect("EditJob.aspx?JOBID=" & txtJobID.Text & "&MSSG=Job%20Saved")
```

with this in pre_render:

```
If strMSSG <> "" Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), 
    "generateSuccess", "generate('Job Saved.', 'success', 'center');", True)
End If
```

and this in the aspx:

```
function generate(text, type, layout) {
    var n = noty({
        text: text,
        type: type,
        dismissQueue: true,
        layout: layout,
        theme: 'defaultTheme',
        buttons: [
            {
                addClass: 'btn btn-primary', text: 'Ok', onClick: function ($noty) {
                    $noty.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log('html: ' + n.options.id);
}
//calls generator with success
function generateSuccess() {
    generate('Success', 'success', 'center');
}
```

I like the look and feel of Noty, which I found in an answer in another question here. But if I hit F5 or the refresh button, the noty is displayed again because of the querystring in the URL.

I have one jquery popup which works, but I can't seem to get more than one on one page. I'd love just another jquery popup, but that doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not good with javascript or jquery, at all, yet.

Comment: (I'm probably the guy that recommended noty). Why are you refreshing the entire page/performing a redirect? Simply creating your noty with `RegisterStartupScript` and manually updating the data sources of any controls that need to have updated data should do the trick, no redirect needed.

Comment: ...I never thought of that... I've been so hung up on getting the order of popup vs page refresh correct that I never thought of anything else. I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: So far so good. All I have to do now is catch the F5 so the page doesn't save the record again. If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to redirect back to the same page in order to display updated data. Just update the data source of any controls that need to display fresh data.

Keep in mind

Request => Process data => Response

Request comes in, you process data, return response. Don't convolute the whole thing with lots of redirects and passing messages around in query string unless you have a real reason to do so (for example, you want to pass a message to another page).